# Is the span of a linearly dependent set equal to a span of a linearly independent subset?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose I have a linearly dependent set. Is it always true that there is a linearly independent subset that has the same span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Zorn's lemma, your set has a maximal linearly independent subset.  Show that its span is the span of the original set.

Comment: Suppose our linearly dependent set is $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ and our maximal linearly independent subset is $x_1, ..., x_m.$ Suppose now that for some $x_i, i > m$ that $x_i$ is not expressible as a linearly combination of our maximal subset. It follows that $x_i \cup \{x_1, ..., x_m\}$ is a linearly independent subset. Hence, contradicting maximality. It follows that every linear combination of $x_1, ..., x_n$ can be written as a linear combination of $x_1, ..., x_m$ by replacing $x_i, i > m.$

Comment: @ntntnt No need to assume these sets are finite.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Every linear space has a basis.

Comment: Oh right the span of a set is also a vector space. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't address the **subset** requirement.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If we remind the proof of this statement...